# MySQL calculated field between dates

Tags: mysql

I am Fairly new to MySQL and I need a calculated field that calculates only in a monthly interval

For example:
I have a `date_created` field and a `daily_hours` field and a `monthly_hours` field

All I need is that `monthly_hours` gets the total value `daily_hours` for this month and enters it into `monthly_hours` as the month progresses

Hope the explanation is clear feel free to ask is more info is needed

Thanks in Advance

```
CREATE TABLE `hours` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`date_created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`fleet_number` int(11) NOT NULL,
`daily_hours` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`monthly_hours` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`next_service_hours_km` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`next_service_in` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

ok so here is my table

data would be as follows

```
id    |date_created        |fleet_number    |daily_hours    |monthly_hours
1     |2016-05-12 22:34:00 |7               |50             |????
2     |2016-05-12 22:34:00 |13              |200            |????
3     |2016-05-13 22:34:00 |7               |55             |????
4     |2016-05-13 22:34:00 |13              |210            |????
```

Hope this is more clear

All I need is the `monthly_hours` to calculate how much hours did each `fleet_number` do for the month so far and insert it into the field `monthly_hours` and start over if its a new month.

```
id    |date_created        |fleet_number    |daily_hours    |monthly_hours
1     |2016-05-12 22:34:00 |7               |50             |0
2     |2016-05-12 22:34:00 |13              |200            |0
3     |2016-05-13 22:34:00 |7               |55             |5
4     |2016-05-13 22:34:00 |13              |220            |20
5     |2016-06-01 22:34:00 |7               |56             |0
6     |2016-06-01 22:34:00 |7               |60             |4
```

Comment: can you update the question with your table definition

Comment: just add show create table statment

Comment: Your explanation is not clear as so far, you can post some sample data and your expected result.

Comment: It is a very bad idea to write the redundant info of monthly hours in the table itself. This will kill you if you edit the rows sometimes. If you need the monthly hours, calculate them from the database with an query.

Comment: The question is still unclear.  You describe `monthly_hours` as the sum of a fleet's `daily_hours` for a month, but your sample data suggests that it is the difference between a fleet's previous `daily_hours`.  (And sample row ID #5 fits neither explanation.)

Comment: Because 50h a day is impossible, I suggest dayly hours is something like a counter, counting up every day from the previous day.

Comment: well guys think of the daily_hours as a total of units like a car's km. that is the total of units on the machine not just what it did for the day my heading is a bit confusing tho sorry for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the query you want:

```
UPDATE `hours` SET `monthly_hours` = (`daily_hours` - (
    SELECT `initial_hours_per_month` FROM  (
    SELECT date_created, Month(`date_created`) as month ,year(`date_created`) as year,fleet_number,  min(daily_hours) as initial_hours_per_month FROM `hours` WHERE 1 group by fleet_number,Month(`date_created`),year(`date_created`)
    ) as `total_times`
    WHERE  `month` = Month(`hours`.`date_created`)
    AND `year` = Year(`hours`.`date_created`)
    AND `hours`.`fleet_number` = `total_times`.`fleet_number`
    ))
```

but I can also recommend a different approach which is to create a view of the total per month,year and fleet_number and to select the relevant row  when you need it:

```
Create view Total_monthly_hours  as (SELECT Month(`date_created`) as month ,year(`date_created`) as year, fleet_number,  min(daily_hours) as initial_hours_per_month FROM `hours` WHERE 1 group by fleet_number, Month(`date_created`), year(`date_created`))
```

With this view :

1. The data will always be updated automatically (in the previous solution you have to run the query each time in order to update numbers, so most of the time data will not be accurate for the last month)
2. You don't save duplication of data. In previous solution you hold duplicated data for each row of same month.

Comment: I think the monthly hours are not the sum off all dayly hours but the difference between the last day of manth dayly hours and the first day of month dayly hours.

Comment: zean said in his question: "all i need is that monthly_hours gets the total value daily_hours"

Comment: Take a look at the example values. There are 50 and 200 dayly hours. Thats impossible. Also the example maonthly hours are calculated by the difference from one day to next day.

Comment: Yes , its totally unclear ..  In the example it looks different than the question. So,  each `daily_hours` is actually the total monthly hours ? and `monthly_hours` is actually the daily gap ?

Comment: sorry for the bad explanation eng isint my first lang lets try again the daily_hours is basically the total of units on the machine like km's on a car it gets changed on a daily basses by 9 or what ever the machine did for the day for example the machine has 1350 total hours and then it worked 9 hours it gets chaned to 1359  my heading is a bit confusing sorry for that . so i need to het the total of hours that changed from the begining of the month till day data was entered in my exaple it shows that from the new month the values chaned back to 0 and start over

Comment: daily_hours thats inserted minus the daily_hours from the start of the month = monthly_hours

Comment: I see. It could be better to give 3 rows in a month in your example because you couldn't know if if to calculate current "daily_hours" minus the previous "daily_hours" , or minus the first "daily_hours", but I understand now what you need.

Comment: I edited the queries of the answer above. please try them and let me know

Comment: view works perfectly im going to use that instead less data used that way didnt even think about data till u guys mentioned haha thanks again Elad for the help. saved me alot of time with trail and error thumbs up

Comment: nope my bad iniatial_hours_per_month does not update as entries are added stays the same but were on the right track

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the syntax but it only showed my the minimum value of daily hours i edited the code to give me what i want

```
Create view Total_monthly_hours  as (
SELECT Month(`date_created`) as month ,
        year(`date_created`) as year, 
        fleet_number,  
        max(daily_hours) - min(daily_hours) as hours_per_month FROM `hours`
        WHERE 1 group by fleet_number, Month(`date_created`), year(`date_created`)
                                    )
```

its not pretty but it works like i said u were on the right track thanks again for the syntax helped me figure out  how to get what i need